# field selection problem?

Tags: blackberry

i am implement a application for blackberry mobile phone. In this application in using datefield for input date. whenever change focus, datefield background will be white...
what i do.

Comment: code is to long but i show u screen shots...

Answer (score 0):

I thin what you want is, every time the datefield is onfocused, the background will be painted white, right ?
I think in that case you have to override the paintBackground and set the color to white.

Comment: thanks for replying sir but this is not my prob...
My prob is that whenever i move the focus from field, the field is become highlighted with white color...

Comment: and what you want to achieve is ? ...
Follow the other guys suggestion, paste some code here.
It will saves you some time.